# Footer needs to stickk to the sidebar at all widths in a responsive theme

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am using yahoo's purecss and trying to create a responsive site. I am facing some issues. The footer is unfortunately, not aligning flush with the sidebar.

[image]

[The Jsfiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/w6cpjfz0/)

the footer css

```
.footer {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgb(100, 100, 100);
border-top: 1px solid #eee;
font-size: 87.5%;
margin-top: 3.4286em;
padding: 1.1429em;
clear: both;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
max-width: 800px;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's blocking it from expanding is :

```
max-width: 800px;
```

is that what you mean by *not aligning flush with the sidebar* ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `.footer` only allows 800px width maximum, remove the `max-width` attribute and it will work. Here is the corrected code:

```
.footer {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgb(100, 100, 100);
border-top: 1px solid #eee;
font-size: 87.5%;
margin-top: 3.4286em;
padding: 1.1429em;
clear: both;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}
```